# Finding Prime Numbers between m to n in java shows me the following error

Tags: java

I have been solving a problem which takes the input of m and n and prints all the prime numbers between m to n included.

When I run in ideone.com Online IDE I get success and my code runs completely fine but the problem here is it takes almost 4864MB memory

https://ideone.com/oXcfeC

Go to the link and check the memory space.
Why does it take that much of memory when the program is very short and not that complicated.`

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Ideone
{
    static class FastReader
{
BufferedReader br;
    StringTokenizer st;

    public FastReader()
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(new
                 InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }

    String next()
    {
        while (st == null || !st.hasMoreElements())
        {
            try
            {
                st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            }
            catch (IOException  e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return st.nextToken();
    }

    int nextInt()
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(next());
    }

    long nextLong()
    {
        return Long.parseLong(next());
    }

    double nextDouble()
    {
        return Double.parseDouble(next());
    }

    String nextLine()
    {
        String str = "";
        try
        {
            str = br.readLine();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    // your code goes here
    FastReader s=new FastReader();
    int t = s.nextInt();
    while(t!=0)
    {
        int m = s.nextInt();
        int n = s.nextInt();
        for(int i = m; i<=n; i++)
        {



            int cnt = 0;
            if( (i>2 && i%2 ==0) || (i>3  && i%3==0) || (i>5 && i%5==0) || (i>7 && i%7 ==0) || (i>11 && i%11 ==0))
            {
                continue;
            }
            for(int j=1;j <=i; j++)
            {
                if(i%j ==0)
                {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
            if(cnt ==2)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            cnt = 0;
        }
        System.out.println("");
        t--;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't close the streams!! This may cause the problem... Use `try-with-resources`

Comment: What does that `FastReader` class do that `Scanner` doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a 'hello, world' in ideone and it gave me memory usage of 4386816KB. So I doubt memory usage in ideone says anything useful at all about your code.

Comment: I dunno... the "world" is pretty big.  Have you tried "Hello, molecule"?

Comment: @ajb Interesting. It gave me 4386816KB for hello, molecule as well. So ideone thinks the world is the same size as a molecule. I think I see the problem...

Comment: Thanks for response!